# What is this sliding window element called?

Tags: terminology, controls, collapsible-panels

I've been trying to figure out the name for this element but I've been having trouble finding it. It should snap in three locations: to the top of the screen, to the bottom of the screen, and a 5th of the way up from the bottom of the screen. The window should be draggable as noted by the three lines.

[image: No idea what this is]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### It's a splitter and pane…

The draggable control itself is a **splitter**, of one kind or another. The separate space that is created by dragging the splitter usually called a **pane** or sometimes a **panel**. To confirm that this is the kind of interaction you meant to describe, have a look at these samples: [Telerik example](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/splitter/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx) or [DevExpress example](https://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxNavigationAndLayoutDemos/Splitter/CollapseExpand.aspx). There are other samples out there, of course.

#### …or perhaps not

This interaction is less likely to be called a **drawer** or an **accordion** section. It all depends on how this interaction is implemented.